# Whats wrong with my PHP include for database connection?

Tags: php, include, include-path, mysql-connect

Im trying to move my database connection script to an external (and therefore more secure) file. However, it isnt working.

Here my PHP page (with include link)

```
<?php
include 'block/datalogin.php';
..etc
```

And heres block/datalogin.php

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "************";
$dbpass = "***********";
$dbname = "************";
@mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("unable to
connect to database."
);
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die ("Unable to select");
```

Im sure the paths and login info are correct.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you mean to have the `@` in front of `mysql_connect`?

Comment: Do you get your "unable to connect to database." or "Unable to select" error messages? Have you enabled PHP show errors?

Comment: @Daniel Still didnt work.. When I have the script copied and pasting directly into my original file (without include) it DOES work...

Comment: @Hossein Doesnt give me any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

---

```
<?php
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "************";
    $dbpass = "***********";
    $dbname = "************";
    $conn=mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("unable to connect to database.");
    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die ("Unable to select");
?>
```

Then use the `$conn` variable in your query's

```
mysql_query("SELECT * from ....",$conn);
```

Comment: are you using the open & close tags `<?php` `?>` put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on the page you include to, it will give you some error you can work with then.

Comment: The `<?php` `?>` did it! I originally left it out because i didnt think an include file would require this

Comment: good glad its working, yeah its required. also if its not parsed as php, some user could visit `block/datalogin.php` and see your logins...

Answer (score 2):

Take out the "@" symbol in front of `mysql_connect`.

Comment: Still didnt work.. When I have the script copied and pasting directly into my original file (without include) it DOES work